# Drilldown in Area Charts

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, highcharts

How do I implement drill down for area charts in High charts using ionic 3 and angular? Can someone please help? There is nothing on google related to this. The high charts library currently only supports drill down for column, pie and bar charts.Can you also tell about how to implement asynchronous drill down in area charts?

Does somebody have any idea regarding this? It would be helpful.

Below is my code for synchronous drilldown. The drilldown is not happening. Can you point out what is wrong with the code?

```
chartOptions : any;
  // reorder: boolean = false;
  // @ViewChild('select') select: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    // this.menu.enable(true, 'app-menu');



      this.chartOptions = {
        chart: {
          type: 'area',
        },
      title: {
          text: 'Operations'
      },
      xAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.value; // clean, unformatted number for year
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Nuclear weapon states'
        },
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.value / 1000 + 'k';
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name} had stockpiled <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>warheads in {point.x}'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        area: {
            pointStart: 1940,
            marker: {
                enabled: false,
                symbol: 'circle',
                radius: 2,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'USA',
        trackByArea: true,
        data: [{
          y: null,
          drilldown: 'driller'
        }, {
          y: null,
          drilldown: 'driller'
        }, {
          y: null,
          drilldown: 'driller'
        },
        {   y: null,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: null,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 6,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 11,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          },{
            y: 32,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 110,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 235,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 369,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 640,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          },{
            y: 1005,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 1436,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 2063,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 3057,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          },{
            y: 4618,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 6444,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 9822,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 15468,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          },{
            y: 20434,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 24126,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 27387,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 29459,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 27387,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 29459,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          },{ 
            y: 32040,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 31233,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          },{
            y: 29224,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 27342,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 26662,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 26956,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          },{
            y: 27912,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 28999,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 28965,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 27826,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          },{
            y: 25579,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 25722,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 24826,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          },{
            y: 24605,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 24304,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 23464,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 23708,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          },{
            y: 24099,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 24357,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 24237,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 24401,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          },{
            y: 24344,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 23586,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 22380,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 21004,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          },{
            y: 17287,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 14747,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 13076,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 12555,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          },{
            y: 12144,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 11009,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 10950,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 10871,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          },{
            y: 10824,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 10577,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 10527,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 10475,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          },{
            y: 10421,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 10358,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 10295,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 10104,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          },{
            y: 9914,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 9620,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 9326,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 5113,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          },{
            y: 5113,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 4954,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 4804,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 4761,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 4717,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          },{
            y: 4368,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }, {
            y: 4018,
            drilldown: 'driller'
          }]


    }, {
        name: 'USSR/Russia',
        data: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
            5, 25, 50, 120, 150, 200, 426, 660, 869, 1060,
            1605, 2471, 3322, 4238, 5221, 6129, 7089, 8339, 9399, 10538,
            11643, 13092, 14478, 15915, 17385, 19055, 21205, 23044, 25393, 27935,
            30062, 32049, 33952, 35804, 37431, 39197, 45000, 43000, 41000, 39000,
            37000, 35000, 33000, 31000, 29000, 27000, 25000, 24000, 23000, 22000,
            21000, 20000, 19000, 18000, 18000, 17000, 16000, 15537, 14162, 12787,
            12600, 11400, 5500, 4512, 4502, 4502, 4500, 4500
        ]
    }],
    drilldown: {
        series: [{
          name: 'Driller series',
          data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 7, 8],
          id: 'driller'
        }]
    }
    }

}
}

HTML code:
<ion-content>
    <chart [options] = "chartOptions" style="display: block" type = "chart"> </chart>
 </ion-content>
```

Comment: Drilldown works the same way for area charts as any other type of charts. The highcharts library supports drilldown on almost all chart types. For area charts; https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.area.data.drilldown

Comment: Can you show me how to implement it using the code for the area chart? IT would be helpful. I used drilldown in my area chart and it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drilldown for an area charts can be done like this:

Set the [**`drilldown for each point`**](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.area.data.drilldown), and enable [**`trackByArea`**](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.trackByArea) (we enable this so that we can click in the middle of a series, and still be drilled down):

```
series: [{
  name: 'Series 1',
  trackByArea: true,
  data: [{y: 1, drilldown: 'drilldownseries'}, 
         {y: 2, drilldown: 'drilldownseries'},
         ...
        ]
  }]
```

Then add the [**`drilldown series`**](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/drilldown.series):

```
drilldown: {
  series: [{
    name: 'Driller series',
    data: [1, 2, 3, ...],
    id: 'drilldownseries'
  }]
}
```

Be sure to include `drilldown.js`, without that module, drilldowns do not work in highcharts.

**Working JSFiddle example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/uaLmg51k/